# How do you solve "undefined function or variable 'mamfis'"?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, ocr, edge-detection, fuzzy-logic

I am doing edge detection on MATLAB r2016a, but I have an error I don't understand. Somewhere I saw that this problem I happens in r2015a, which is why I upgraded to r2016a, but I get the same problem:

> undefined function or variable 'mamfis'

Also, I get this error as well:

> Error: File: edge.m Line: 48 Column: 6 
>   The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.

```
Irgb = imread('IMG_1769.png');
Igray = rgb2gray(Irgb);

figure
image(Igray,'CDataMapping','scaled')
colormap('gray')
title('Input Image in Grayscale')
I = im2double(Igray);
Gx = [-1 1];
Gy = Gx';
Ix = conv2(I,Gx,'same');
Iy = conv2(I,Gy,'same');
figure
image(Ix,'CDataMapping','scaled')
colormap('gray')
title('Ix')
figure
image(Iy,'CDataMapping','scaled')
colormap('gray')
title('Iy')
% edgeFIS=mamfis;
edgeFIS = mamfis('Name','edgeDetection');
edgeFIS = addInput(edgeFIS,[-1 1],'Name','Ix');
edgeFIS = addInput(edgeFIS,[-1 1],'Name','Iy');
sx = 0.1;
sy = 0.1;
edgeFIS = addMF(edgeFIS,'Ix','gaussmf',[sx 0],'Name','zero');
edgeFIS = addMF(edgeFIS,'Iy','gaussmf',[sy 0],'Name','zero');
edgeFIS = addOutput(edgeFIS,[0 1],'Name','Iout');
wa = 0.1;
wb = 1;
wc = 1;
ba = 0;
bb = 0;
bc = 0.7;
edgeFIS = addMF(edgeFIS,'Iout','trimf',[wa wb wc],'Name','white');
edgeFIS = addMF(edgeFIS,'Iout','trimf',[ba bb bc],'Name','black');
figure
subplot(2,2,1)
plotmf(edgeFIS,'input',1)
title('Ix')
subplot(2,2,2)
plotmf(edgeFIS,'input',2)
title('Iy')
subplot(2,2,[3 4])
plotmf(edgeFIS,'output',1)
title('Iout')
r1 = "If Ix is zero and Iy is zero then Iout is white";
r2 = "If Ix is not zero or Iy is not zero then Iout is black";
edgeFIS = addRule(edgeFIS,[r1 r2]);
edgeFIS.Rules

Ieval = zeros(size(I));
for ii = 1:size(I,1)
    Ieval(ii,:) = evalfis(edgeFIS,[(Ix(ii,:));(Iy(ii,:))]');
end

figure
image(I,'CDataMapping','scaled')
colormap('gray')
title('Original Grayscale Image')

figure
image(Ieval,'CDataMapping','scaled')
colormap('gray')
title('Edge Detection Using Fuzzy Logic')
```

Comment: Do the release notes for r2016a make any mention of fixing the error you were trying to escape from r2015a? New versions of software don't usually fix *every single problem* from the previous version.

Comment: When upgrading, it is recommended to upgrade to the latest release, not a release that is 8 releases behind.

Answer (score 1):

First problem, the [`mamfis`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/mamfis.html) function is from the Fuzzy Logic Toolbox, so you need that toolbox installed to use it. It doesn't exist in core MATLAB.

Second problem, defining [strings](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html) using double quotes (`"`) wasn't added until MATLAB version R2017a. You need to define a character array using single quotes (`'`).

Comment: I understood now and let me check once if it's done for me